# How to view HTML source code in custom text editor with IE9?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I am looking for a way to have IE9 open source code in a custom application that I choose by default such as Notepad, Notepad2, or even Word if I want.

Note:  This is for `View Source`, not changing what application I use to edit an HTML file.

**Edit:**  I do not believe this qualifies as a complete duplicate.  The other question specifically asks about IE8.  I removed all IE version tags except IE9 and also addressed Windows 7.  Since that other question is nearly four years old, it is possible that the asker was dealing with XP or Vista although it wasn't mentioned.  Additionally, I could not find that registry key even through a search.

Comment: This may be interesting to those using FireFox, this is available with the following https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dafizilla-viewsourcewith/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Open Internet Explorer and then press F12 to open the F12 developer
>   tools. On the File menu select File and then Customize Internet
>   Explorer View Source. Here you can select the familiar Default Viewer,
>   Notepad, or Other (which allows you to specify a different program,
>   such as a third-party Web editor).

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh133451.aspx via http://blogs.technet.com/b/tnmag/archive/2011/05/10/change-the-default-app-for-viewing-source-in-internet-explorer.aspx